# invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript,/etc/init.d/modemmanager not found

Tags: apt, ubuntu-touch, dpkg

I booted Ubuntu 13.10 in my Android tablet and works good but after installing some programs I have this error

```
u0_a206@Android:/ $
u0_a206@Android:/ $ su
root@Android:/ # /data/data/com. Zpwebsites. Linuxonandroid/files/busybox chroot /data/local/mnt /root/init.sh
Config file loaded

New 'X' desktop is localhost: 0

Starting applications specified in /home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/ubuntu/.vnc/localhost:0.log


If you see the message 'New 'X' Desktop is localhost: 0' then you are ready to VNC into your Ubuntu OS.

If connection from a different machine on the same network as the Android device use the address below:
wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found

If using androidVNC, change the 'Color Format' setting to 24-bit colour, and once you've VNC'd in, change the 'input mode' to touchpad (in settings)
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                                                                                                             [ OK ] 
To shut down the Linux environment, just enter 'exit' at this terminal - and WAIT for all shutdown routines to finish!

Root@localhost:/#
root@localhost:/# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up modemmanager (0.6.0.0.really-0ubuntu7) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript,/etc/init.d/modemmanager not found.
dpkg: error processing modemmanager (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 modemmanager
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@localhost:/#'
```

I can't install anything any update and upgrade 
I tryed some answers from this here and other forums but doesn't work

Answer (score 7):

This is very simple to fix.

invoke-rc.d(Invoke an init script) is unable to find the initscript `/etc/init.d/modemmanager`

`invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript,/etc/init.d/modemmanager not found.`

Simply `touch /etc/init.d/modemmanager` To create it.

Comment: Had the same problem installing ubuntu-desktop with tasksel into a dbootstrap 14.04. This solved it along with an equivilent command `touch /etc/init.d/whoopsie` Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First download the `modemmanager` package by running,

```
apt-get download modemmanager
```

After that completely remove the unconfigured `modemmanager` package by running the below command,

```
sudo dpkg -P modemmanager
```

Then do an upgrade,

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

In case if you failed to connect to the internet after uninstalling modemmanager, don't worry we already downloaded the modemmanager package.It will be located on your home directory.Install it by running,

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

Comment: You booted Ubuntu on android.This solution may or maynot works.

Comment: He already had modemmanager, the upgrade was just reconfiguring it, but in was improperley configured, so a simple fix it to make an empty initscript